# What well developed iteratee/pipes libraries are available for Scala?

Tags: scala, java, loops

Does Scala have any well developed libraries in the spirit of Haskell's pipes, or at least [iteratee](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/iteratee)?

I found Play's iteratee library first, but I couldn't make it work, and it seems tightly coupled with Play's concurrency primitive `Promise`, which could be inappropriate in many cases.

Scalaz has some iteratee support (like [IterV](http://scalaz.github.com/scalaz/scalaz-2.9.0-1-6.0/doc/scalaz/IterV.html)), but it seems there are only core classes with no additional support functions, predefined iteratees/enumerators etc. Also I couldn't find any documentation, even scaladoc is very sparse, so it's quite difficult to use properly.

And I couldn't find anything similar to *pipes*.

Comment: +1 (and not sure why people are voting to close). Have you had a look at the [`iteratee` package in Scalaz 7](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/tree/scalaz-seven/iteratee/src/main/scala/scalaz/iteratee)? It doesn't have as many batteries included as the Haskell iteratee libraries, but it's much more usable than the Scalaz 6 version.

Comment: Also, there is [a Scala port](https://github.com/arjanblokzijl/scala-conduits) of Michael Snoyman's [Conduit library](https://github.com/snoyberg/conduit) (which I've personally found clearer than pipes, coming from iteratees—but I've not yet tried the Scala port).

Comment: there is an awesome lib based on play iteratees http://blog.greweb.fr/2013/01/playcli-play-iteratees-unix-pipe/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Building up on comments from Travis, currently there are:

- Scalaz 7 [iteratee](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/tree/scalaz-seven/iteratee/src/main/scala/scalaz/iteratee) package (iterv, you mentioned, is a compatibility layer with scalaz 6)
- A [port of Conduit library](https://github.com/arjanblokzijl/scala-conduits)
- Runar's [scala-machines](https://github.com/runarorama/scala-machines) library ([presentation](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4588997/Machines.pdf), [haskell version](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/machines))

Comment: Runar's machines look very interesting, I'll look into it. Unfortunately, as they're in development, they seem to lack documentation (as AFAIK Scalaz 7 iteratee does). The port of _conduit_ seems promising, but I'm not sure if it's being developed or if it's meant to be finished. Its development [seems to have stopped](https://github.com/arjanblokzijl/scala-conduits/graphs/commit-activity) about 6 months ago and there is no sign of pronouncing it ready or finished.

Comment: For Scalaz 7, I've got an example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13389530/334519) with a fair amount of detail, and my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13422756/334519) (with [this solution](https://gist.github.com/travisbrown/4091180)) is about making it work a little more like Millikin's Haskell library.